# BadRequest in Power Automate while the attachment is uploaded to Sharepoint

Tags: forms, sharepoint, power-automate

I am setting up a flow in Power Automate to retrieve details from a Microsoft Form.

What it does:

- Get the reponse details from Microsoft Forms
- Creating a new item in a Sharepoint list
- If one of the questions is answered with yes, the following will run:
- Parsing JSON
- Get the file content and metadata using path
- Add attachment to Sharepoint in the list
- Get the items
- Add the same attachment to a database folder in a Sharepoint folder

It goes wrong in the last step where I have some "apply to each"-statements. Somehow it does save the file to the correct folder, but it does give an error in the flow itself. I have read multiple forums regarding this problem, but it does not seem to solve mine.

[image: I screenshotted the results here]

Update:

I was able to clear up the error in the end. However, the "Apply to each" still gives an error. The file has been updated in the folder.

[Apply to each runs, but still gives error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYRTt.png)

Please help :(!

Comment: What's in the outputs?  There's a button there, "click to download", can you provide that information in your question?

Comment: Hi @Skin, I added some additional information. I was able to get rid of the error at the last step (there was already a file with that name...) However, if I run it now it does give green light for all steps, but not for the overall, giving the same problem as before. Any idea?